# Android - Use and change Array in whole class

Tags: java, android, arrays

Im trying to solve this problem for about 2 hours. So Im glad for every possible answer. 
Ive got a custom ListViewAdapter and it takes his content from an Array. But I have 19 Arrays and I want to change the Content(therefor the Array) based on which date the User clicks(there is a Calendar on the top with 19 Dates). 
Here is a picture:

[image]

So by default ervy time you open the App the content from the "date_1" Array will be shown(for the 25. in the calender). And when you click on an other date the content from the Array belonging to this date will be shown(e.g. 26. -> date_2, 27. date_3 and so on).
Every Array has to get load from the resources and is saved in a single Array Variable.

**So my problem:** 
I can't change the Array. Here is my code:

```
// this is the Array Variable:

   String[] day_chosen;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.calender);
          [...]
            prepareArrayLits();
            lview3 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

            adapter = new ListViewCustomAdapter(this, itemList);
            lview3.setAdapter(adapter);

            lview3.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        }

        public void onItemClick1(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        /* Method used to prepare the ArrayList,
         */

        public void prepareArrayLits()
        {
            // this is where the Arrays get loaded from the resource:
             day_chosen = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.date_1);

//this Array is not relvant:
            String[] sports = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sports_array);


            itemList = new ArrayList<Object>();
             for (int counter = 0; counter < day_chosen.length; counter+=4){


                 int Intparser = Integer.parseInt(day_chosen[counter+1]);


                 AddObjectToList(imgid(Intparser),  sports[Intparser],day_chosen[counter],day_chosen[counter+3], backgroundbox(Intparser)) ;
             }


        }

        // Add one item into the Array List
        public void AddObjectToList(int image, String title, String desc, String time, int backbox)
        {

            bean = new ItemBean();
            bean.setBackBox(backbox);
            bean.setTime(time);
            bean.setDescription(desc);
            bean.setImage(image);
            bean.setTitle(title);
            itemList.add(bean);
        }

       [...]
        }

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

// the onClick Events for every date:
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub




              switch(v.getId()){

              case R.id.d_1 :
// I tried to change the Array from here(But it didn't work):
                  day_chosen = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.date_1);


                  break;

              case R.id.d_2 :
                  day_chosen = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.date_2);

                  break;
              [...]

        }



    }
```

**What have I tried:**

- I set up a Global Class but it didn't work
- I tried to set up getters and setters. But also didn't work

I don't know how to solve this. Every possible solution is appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you exactly implements your Adapter but did you call `yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` when your list content is changed?

Comment: This shouldn't be the problem. The problem is I can't change the Array( String[] day_chosen; from an other methode)

Comment: @user1253575 you keep saying this, so are you getting an error, because I actually agree with eyal-lezmy on this.

Comment: Sorry to insist but I'm quiet sure it is that, you should try to add it  as it is shown by Salil Pandit below.
Another thing, you should try to think about getting your  `getResources().getStringArray` before your `onClick` handling because this operation could make your interface laggy and cause [ANR](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/responsiveness.html). I hope this will help.

Answer (score 2):

So I'm guessing when you click on a Date at the top the content below changes. There are a variety of ways to do this. To solve your current problem in your current code, here is what you are going to want to do:
Based on the code you've shown, I'm assuming that somewhere you have a line of code that looks like: `new MyHappyAdapter(... itemList, ...)` where you are passing the itemList reference, probably some kind of `ArrayAdapter`.
If so you are going to want to add this right after your switch statement:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
     switch(v.getId()){

          case R.id.d_1 :
              // I tried to change the Array from here(But it didn't work):
              day_chosen = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.date_1);
              break;

          case R.id.d_2 :
              day_chosen = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.date_2);
              break;
     }
 //Remove the old items from the list
 itemList.clear();
 //Force it setup the list again
 prepareArrayLits();
 //Tell the adapter to update the view
 adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
 }
```

The `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()` call tells the adapter to refresh the `ListView`.

As a side note, I wouldn't actually recommend you continue down this path. I'd suggest you turn this into a `ViewPager` where each date is a `Tab` and the content below is a `ListFragment`. You can read about `ViewPager` and the support jar [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html).